# Remove an event listener in a function declared/contained within the function that added the listener

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

This may be a very stupid question but I'd like to understand the reasons behind it. I apologize for the poor question title.

The code below works. When the btn element has a mousedown event, a menu is displayed, and an event listener is added to hide the menu for a mousedown event anywhere within the document. If btn is clicked while the menu is displayed, then the event is not added again but it is removed by invoking the function clear. So, nothing special at all.

What I don't understand and wasted much time on is that, if the clear function is declared within the menu_func, the event listener on the document is not removed upon the second btn mousedown event. (By that I mean simply move the closing brace of menu_func to after the closing brace of the clear function.) The clear function is invoked and the rest of the code is performed, but the event listener is not removed until the document has a mouse down event and then it logs multiple removed event listener messages.

If nothing was written to the console log, one would think the code worked either way, but it doesn't really.

Please explain what I'm not understanding here.  Thank you.

```
btn.addEventListener( 'mousedown', menu_func, false );


function menu_func(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation(); 
    let e = evt.currentTarget;
    if ( e.disp ) { 
        clear();
    }
    else { 
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', clear, false );
        e.disp = true;
        /* Some CSS style code to display menu. */
        console.log('Event Listener Added');
    }; // end if         
} // close menu_func

function clear() {
    document.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', clear, false );
    e.disp = false;                 
    /* Some CSS style code to remove menu. */
    console.log('Event Listener Removed');
} // close clear
```